# Does std::istringstream::imbue own the object passed

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using Boost to convert a date of the form "01-Jan-2000" to a julian number. The way I do this is to use

```
int toJulian(std::string date)
{
    std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%d-%b-%Y"));
    std::istringstream ss(date);
    ss.imbue(loc);
    boost::posix_time::ptime p;
    ss >> p;
    return p.date().julian_day();
}
```

(This is along the lines of the examples in the Boost documentation).

But it's not clear to me if this leaks memory or not. I don't have an explicit `delete`. Obviously if `imbue` passes ownership of the pointer in `loc` to the stream then perhaps it's deleted when `ss` goes out of scope.

Am I correct?

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags

Comment: The example on cppreference seems to also not delete the `Facet`. Interesting that it doesn't mention that. Normally I'd assume that a raw pointer means non-owning...

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Stole your thunder on this: cppreference.com has a note saying the locale deletes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **No, but the std::locale object does**.

You want to be looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

You are calling the constructor (overload 7)

```
template< class Facet >
locale( const locale& other, Facet* f );
```

The linked reference is clear:

> Overload 7 is typically called with its second argument, f, obtained
>   directly from a new-expression: the locale is responsible for calling
>   the matching delete from its own destructor.

So yes, something will `delete` the object for you, but it's actually the `std::locale` instance that does it, **not** the stream.

Comment: I was trying to find a corresponding standard quote, but couldn't (except 25.3.1.1.2.3)

Comment: I'm a naughty cat: I treat en.cppreference.com as the standard. But I'll upvote any answer of yours that contains a standard quote ;-)

Comment: That's odd because 22.3.1.1.2 [locale.facet] says that the `facet` constructor takes a flag which indicates whether the facet should be deleted or not. (The flag defaults to deletion.)  So it depends on how `boost::posix_time::time_input_facet` calls its base class constructor.  (I'm using n4296 as the Standard, which is intermediate between cppreference and the real thing - but the difference is pretty marginal).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Interesting. Trawling through my boost, it has a parameter ref_arg which is defaulted to 0. This calls the C++ standard library constructor with that ref_arg. Seems like an initial reference count argument to me. So in the OP's case the locale destructor will delete the facet. Hopefully a decent answer will come along and tie up Boost, cppreference, the standard and my MSVC2015 C++ standard library implementation!